# Limit of an integral of a continuous function

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}_+$ and suppose that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$. Show that: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt = a$$

I considered the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, getting that above limit is equal to: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}$$
However, I'm not sure how to conclude the equality with $a$ from this step.

Comment: no, that is not the definition of the derivative. For that, $x$ would have to tend to $0$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and choose $R\in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$|f(x)-a| < \varepsilon $$ if $x>R$. Then, for any $s>R$ 
$$(s-R)(a-\varepsilon) < \int_R^s f(x) < (s-R)(a+\varepsilon)$$
Now divide by $s$ and let $s\rightarrow \infty$.

*Edit*: Note: just to make sure you do not overlook this: this quietly assumes that $\int_0^Rf(x)dx$ is finite for any finite $R>0$, which is true, for example, if $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. If $f$ is continuous only on $(0, \infty)$, this may not work (it is still sufficient if the integral from $0$ to $R$ is finite for any $R$, you just cannot prove this anymore) and the statement you are after might actually not be true.

Comment: Good answer. Surely neater than mine.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is NOT the definition of the derivative. (Better check it out in your textbook yourself)

For a short proof.  Your limit is just $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)/x$.  Now that since the denominator goes to infinity, and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F'(x)/x'=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=a$ exists. By l'Hospital we can claim that  $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)/x=a$.

(PS: in the strongest version of l'Hospital we don't necessarily need both the numerator and denominator tends to infinity simultaneously. We only require the latter)

Comment: Are you sure about that last remark? That would seem to imply that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(1/x^{10})}{1/x}$ isn't zero.

Comment: Same as mine!  +1

Comment: @Ian Before applying whatever version of LHR to make a claim, you must first ensure the existence of $\lim f'(x)/g'(x)$.

Comment: @Ian The example you provided does not refute L'Hospital's Rule.  See Note 2 of [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#General_proof).

Comment: Ah, OK; then your statement is still a little bit deceptive, I think. You need that $g$ blows up and that the limit of the ratio of the derivatives exists. Saying "if $g$ blows up then limit of $f/g$ is the limit of $f'/g'$" makes it sound like "if $g$ blows up then the limit of $f/g$ and the limit of $f'/g'$ either both exist or both don't exist and are equal if they exist", which my example refutes.

Comment: @Ian yeah but that spares us the trouble to prove $f(x)$ blows up, sometimes it means removing a lot of pain.

Comment: @Ian By the way, when g blows up the limit might also be zero. (Not in this case, though

Comment: @Ian L'Hospital's Rule says that if the limit of $\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists, and $g\to \infty$, then $\lim\frac{f}{g}=\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$.

Comment: It doesn't save that much pain in this case; as soon as $f$ is within $a/2$ of $a$ for all $x>M$, $\int_M^\infty f(x) dx$ is $\text{sign}(a) \cdot \infty$.

Comment: $a$ could be zero.  So, that is not generally true.

Comment: @Dr.MV I agree, but I think Vim's statement is prone to the misreading that I gave above.

Comment: @Vim sorry about the part of the definition of derivative, of course it isn't... In fact, I considered L'Hôpital,but I didn't know this version of such theorem!

Comment: Fair point, the case $f(a)=0$ would require a separate analysis in that approach. I guess the L'Hospital approach saves that bit of pain.

Comment: @jggarita In my answer, I provided a reference for the proof with Note 2 discussing this issue.

Comment: @Ian Yes!  That is the reason it is the most efficient approach here.

Comment: @jggarita Never mind. By the way for the reference of this version you can see  the one in Dr.MV's answer.

Comment: Actually, when I work out the kinks in that approach, what I get is Thomas's approach. That is, the inequality that I wind up with when I bring in the $\varepsilon$ I need (since just the divergence isn't enough) is exactly the inequality Thomas got. Fun problem!

Answer (score 3):

Using [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#General_proof), we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^xf(t)dt}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=f(a)$$

**NOTE:**

L'Hospital's Rule does not require that the limit of the numerator approach $\infty$ as shown in Note 2 of [THIS REFERENCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#General_proof).

Comment: You are right. I wasn't sure about your claim, but actually it is true. For another reference, check Bartle & Sherbert's Introduction to real analysis (they call it L'Hospital's rule II)

Comment: @jggarita Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really wanted to give you the best answer I could, but didn't receive any positive feedback.

Comment: This is one of best uses of L'Hospital's rule. Unfortunately it is used mostly to solve routine problems of limit evaluation (examples abound on MSE). +1